# Centering Spanned Columns with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout, jdialog

I have a JDialog in which I have a series of columns over which I want to center a JLabel. I cannot seem to find anything on how to do that. I can center it within a cell but not within a spanned set of columns. The labels in this image "Target" and "Change" need to be centered.
[image: Time Line Settings]

Here is the SSCCE that produces this JDialog.

```
package stokerMonitor;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;


public class test {

static JDialog timeLineDialog;
static int row=0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    timeLineDialog = new JDialog();
    timeLineDialog.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    timeLineDialog.setModalityType(ModalityType.MODELESS);
    timeLineDialog.setTitle("Time Line Settings");
    timeLineDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel("Time");
    JLabel actionLabel = new JLabel("Action");
    JLabel probeTempLabel=null;
    JLabel pitTempLabel=null;
    JLabel targetHeader=new JLabel("Target");
    Font boldFont=targetHeader.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, (float) 14);
    targetHeader.setFont(boldFont);
    JLabel changeHeader=new JLabel("Change");
    changeHeader.setFont(boldFont);
    if (Configuration.getInstance().celsius) {
        probeTempLabel = new JLabel("Temp (\u00B0 C)");
        pitTempLabel = new JLabel("Temp (\u00B0 C)");
    }
    else {
        probeTempLabel = new JLabel("Temp (\u00B0 F)");
        pitTempLabel = new JLabel("Temp (\u00B0 F)");
    }
    JLabel meatLabel=new JLabel("Meat");
    JLabel cookTimeLabel=new JLabel("Est. Time");
    JLabel weightLabel=new JLabel("Weight");
    JLabel probeLabel=new JLabel("Probe");
    JLabel pitLabel=new JLabel("Pit");
    setNewSeparator(1,row);
    GridBagConstraints gbc=makeGbc(2, row);
    gbc.gridwidth=7;
    gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    timeLineDialog.add(targetHeader,gbc);
    setNewSeparator(9,row);
    timeLineDialog.add(changeHeader,makeGbc(10, row));
    setNewSeparator(12,row++);
    setNewSeparator(1,row);
    timeLineDialog.add(timeLabel, makeGbc(2, row));
    timeLineDialog.add(probeTempLabel,makeGbc(3, row));
    timeLineDialog.add(meatLabel,makeGbc(4, row));
    timeLineDialog.add(weightLabel,makeGbc(5, row));
    timeLineDialog.add(cookTimeLabel,makeGbc(6, row));
    timeLineDialog.add(probeLabel,makeGbc(7, row));
    timeLineDialog.add(actionLabel, makeGbc(8, row));
    setNewSeparator(9,row);
    timeLineDialog.add(pitLabel,makeGbc(10, row));
    timeLineDialog.add(pitTempLabel, makeGbc(11, row++));
    setNewSeparator(12,row);
    timeLineDialog.pack();
    timeLineDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(GUI.getInstance().getFrame());
    timeLineDialog.setVisible(true);
}

static void setNewSeparator(int column_,int row_) {
    JSeparator sep=new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
    sep.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1,1));
    GridBagConstraints gbc=makeGbc(column_, row_);
    gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gbc.weighty=1.;
    timeLineDialog.add(sep,gbc);
}

static GridBagConstraints makeGbc(int x, int y) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      Insets WEST_INSETS=new Insets(5,0,5,5);
      Insets EAST_INSETS=new Insets(5,5,5,0);
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;

      gbc.anchor = (x == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.WEST : GridBagConstraints.EAST;
      gbc.fill = (x == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.BOTH
            : GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

      gbc.insets = (x == 0) ? WEST_INSETS : EAST_INSETS;
      gbc.weightx = (x == 0) ? 0.1 : 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      return gbc;
   }
}
```

Can someone explain what I need to do to center those headers? TIA.

Comment: Use a [gridwidth](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#gridwidth) larger than 1 to span multiple columns.

Comment: @VGR He does already have `gridwidth=7`, at least for `targetHeader`.  (I didn't look at the other one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tip: when debugging layouts, I find it useful to set each component to have a different background color.  Then I can see the area assigned to / filled by that particular component.  Most components default to a transparent background, which means their bounds is not visible.  (eg `targetHeader.setOpaque(true); targetHeader.setBackground(Color.RED);`)

The situation you have with your layout is that the JLabel fills the 7 columns you specified.  However, the label itself draws the text it contains in the leftmost part of the space that it fills.

There are two alternative solutions:

1. Tell the label that you want it to center the text within the label: 
   `targetHeader.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);`
2. Alternatively, you can tell the layout to *not* fill the space. 
   `gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.NONE;`

Comment: Thanks. I used gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.NONE; and that did the trick. I need to re-read those values as it seems to be the opposite of what the name implies.

Comment: The GBC fill constants do exactly what what they say. Set the background, and opacity, of the label to see it visually. With `fill=NONE`, the label does not fill the cell(s). With `fill=HORIZONTAL`, then the label does fill it; the label just draws the text starting at the left of the area the label has (unless you set the label's own horizontal alignment otherwise). The GBC's anchor is only meaningful when the component does not fill, since if the component fills the space it doesn't then matter where the component starts. The key is the interaction between the various properties and values.

Comment: *"Tip: when debugging layouts, I find it useful to set each component to have a different background color."* I'll read the rest of your answer, but you get an up vote for that 'teach a man to fish' enabling comment. Nice one:) Many layout issues come down to the OP presuming a component will be stretched to size when it's not, or a layout constraint resulting in more or less columns or rows being assigned than they expect. Setting the BG color should be considered a kind of 'acid test' of the layout assumptions used in the code.

Answer (score 1):

As VGR said in his comment, you should be setting a gridwidth in your constraints to make it easier for GridBagLayout to understand how to treat the two top labels.

I would set the gridwidth for the Target Label to 7, and set the gridwidth for the Change Label to 2. All the labels below should be set to one.

Then when you set GridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstants.CENTER;, it should do the behavior you are looking for.

EDIT: I said Target label to 5, but I meant 7.